# Вылетает java.lang.OutOfMemoryError при попытке открывать DialogFragment

Tags: android, java

Я пытаюсь по нажатию на кнопку контекстного меню вызвать объект DialogFragment, но, увы, вылетает:

```
03-27 13:44:28.545    1685-1685/com.HelloWorld.timextendsreminder.app E/art﹕ Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 25376944 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 19MB until OOM"
--------- beginning of crash
03-27 13:44:28.546    1685-1685/com.HelloWorld.timextendsreminder.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ Error reporting crash
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 25376944 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 19MB until OOM
```

Погуглил, часто это исключение вылетает у тех, кто работает с BitmapFactory/Bitmap, я же с ними в этом приложение не имею дела. Пытался очищать код DialogFragment, чтобы хотя бы просто высвечивало простой диалог, но без толку.

Кто нибудь сталкивался?

Код DialogFragment

```
Alarm alarm;
EditText edit;
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    alarm = new Alarm();
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setView(getLayoutInflater(savedInstanceState).inflate(R.layout.edit, null))
            .setTitle("Rename the task:")
            .setPositiveButton("OK",this)
            .setNegativeButton("Back",this);
    Dialog d = new Dialog(getActivity());
    edit = (EditText) d.findViewById(R.id.msg_et);
    return builder.create();
}
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(edit.getText())) {
        alarm.setName(edit.getText().toString());
        alarm.persist(RemindMe.db);
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Enter a message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

`Alarm` - класс-модель таблицы в БД.

Фрагмент кода с вызываемой Activity:

```
 case CM_EDIT:
            editDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"editDialog");
            break;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего ошибка в этом месте:

```
getLayoutInflater(savedInstanceState)
```

Уберите оттуда **Bundle**, чтобы получилось просто:

```
getActivity().getLayoutInflater()
```

вызываемое из активити.

---

**P.S.** Впервые вижу, чтобы Bundle в сей метод пихали, загнал в гугл строку

> [getLayoutInflater(savedInstanceState)](https://www.google.ru/search?q=getLayoutInflater(savedInstanceState)&oq=getLayoutInflater(savedInstanceState)&aqs=chrome..69i57.552j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

И [первая же ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8900918/3212712) подтвердила мои подозрения)

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Я когда раньше использовал этот метод, тоже оставлял его без параметра, но вот, написав его тут, он начал ругаться, что нет параметра, нужно было вызвать его из getActitvity(). Еще раз большое спасибо!

Comment: @Dandewine, пожалуйста)